# Why can't I set up a jenkins agent on the same machine as the master (WIndows 10), Jenkins on localhost?

Tags: jenkins

Can't set up an agent on the same machine as the master node in Jenkins. The Jenkins instance is on localhost as is the agent. The main problem I'm getting is:

```
    at

        yah de yah.....

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: http://192.168.0.1:8080/
```

Here's what I tried:

1 - Configure agent launched via ssh, Host is http://192.168.0.1:8080/ (also tried 127.0.0.1 and localhost here but the URL in Jenkins config is as shown) with Jenkins admin password. Used 'Known host file Verification Strategy' Advanced setting uses port 22. Tried Jenkins Global Security settings with fixed port 22, 50000 and random port setting.

Also toggled Windows OpenSSH for client and server with the above combinations.

2. Configure agent by Connecting it to the master; other options as default. Got 'Agent is offline because Jenkins failed to launch the agent process' and got the 'Launch' button for webstart. Clicked on that; nothing happened (that I saw) but the file did appear in my downloads folder.

Copied the file to another directory, opened a command window in that directory and entered the 'headless' command shown in the window with the webstart button. Got:

`Error: Unable to access jarfile agent.jar`

Seems no matter what I try I can't connect to http://192.168.0.1:8080/

Is this some sort of tunneling issue where I need to expose localhost even though I'm not going over the Internet? I needed to do that to get my localhost Jenkins install to talk to GitHub.

Been reading numerous articles,watched videos - seems most of the material out there is for a 'real' use of creating agents on separate machines.

Any advice would be MOST appreciated.

Comment: Using a local host ip causes all sorts of issues with Jenkins. Try using `ngrok` which will give your server an actual IP address.

Comment: Thanks gorbysbm

I gotta give your suggestion a try this is one of those itches I couldn't scratch!